# Rails formatting in edit field

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Can rails formatting helpers be used on an 'edit' screen?  The format helpers (`number_to_currency`, `number_to_percent`) are great for index/show, but I don't see how to apply them during edit. I have a custom heler that formats the date:

```
def my_date_helper(datetime)
    datetime.nil? ? "" : datetime.strf('%d-%b-%Y')
end
```

For example, if I have a `starts_at` attribute, that the user interacts with using a jQuery datepicker, the value placed in edit.html.erb in `<%= f.text_field :starts_at %>` by rails will be formatted like:

`2011/12/19 00:00:00`

I would like the user to be presented with a consistent format,so I want to apply the same format helper I use in show/index so the edit text field shows a format like:

`19-Jan-2011`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had a 'duh' moment.  To doesn't seem there's any easy, rails-ey way.  But it can be done really easy with unobtrusive JavaScript, like:

```
  $('.datepicker').each(function(i){
    var date = new Date($(this).val());
    $(this).val($.datepicker.formatDate('dd-M-yy', date));
  });
```

Four lines in `application.js` and you're done.

Answer (score 5):

You could do this for your edit form:

```
<%= f.text_field :starts_at, :value => my_date_helper(@my_model.starts_at) %>
```

Also, jQuery's Date Picker includes a `dateFormat` parameter, so you could do something like this in your javascript:

```
jQuery("#my_model_starts_at").datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'd/M/yy'
});
```

Comment: This is pretty good, but instead of using my_date_helper, I'd define `Date::DATE_FORMATS[:ymd] = "%Y-%m-%d"` in environment.rb and then call `:value => @my_mode.starts_at.to_s(:ymd)`. That way, you can use this format in any model (or outside of a model).

Comment: Definitely a great suggestion. I actually have a `date_formats.rb` initializer that sets a bunch of custom date and time formats that I use in my projects.

Comment: I don't like using :value=> in the views.  It's the controllers job to decide the value

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery('#datetimepicker3').datetimepicker({
  format:'d.m.Y H:i',
  inline:true,
  lang:'ru'
});
```

[datetimepicker](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/)